# List<T> capacity increasing vs Dictionary<K,V> capacity increasing?

Tags: c#, .net

Why does `List<T>` increase its capacity by a factor of 2?

```
private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
{
    if (this._items.Length < min)
    {
        int num = (this._items.Length == 0) ? 4 : (this._items.Length * 2);
        if (num < min)
        {
            num = min;
        }
        this.Capacity = num;
    }
}
```

Why does `Dictionary<K,V>` use prime numbers as capacity?

```
private void Resize()
{
    int prime = HashHelpers.GetPrime(this.count * 2);
    int[] numArray = new int[prime];
    for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
    {
        numArray[i] = -1;
    }
    Entry<TKey, TValue>[] destinationArray = new Entry<TKey, TValue>[prime];
    Array.Copy(this.entries, 0, destinationArray, 0, this.count);
    for (int j = 0; j < this.count; j++)
    {
        int index = destinationArray[j].hashCode % prime;
        destinationArray[j].next = numArray[index];
        numArray[index] = j;
    }
    this.buckets = numArray;
    this.entries = destinationArray;
}
```

Why doesn't it also just multiply by 2? Both are dealing with finding *continues memory location*...correct?

Comment: You should not post source code of the .NET framework. (I assume it is.)

Comment: @StefanSteinegger and exactly why is that?

Comment: If it makes the question easier to understand - why not?

Comment: What would `Initialize` multiply by 2? It's called once, when the `Dictionary` is constructed, and never again after that. That's why it's called `Initialize`.

Comment: I was looking at @StefanSteinegger's comment, by the way, and from the "legal" link at the bottom of every page: "You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license." If the code isn't yours, you have no right to share it under a CC license. (Not that that's enforced too strictly.)

Comment: Why do you assume `int prime = HashHelpers.GetPrime(this.count * 2);` is not prime? I would guess GetPrime returns the next largest prime

Comment: @HugoRune grrrr you right. it cross my mind that the 2 is outside the phrase (it happens...:-)

Comment: Another reason for not posting non-public code from microsoft is that it makes things harder for any mono developer. To legally do a clean reimplementation of the .net framework, they must not have seen the .net source.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger does adding `My_Function_ `prfix will solve this issue ?

Comment: You cannot legally publish any source code you get from decompilation, no matter what you call the functions. Microsoft most likely will not enforce this for such small samples, but the principle of the matter is that this code is owned by microsoft.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: no, it wont. hvd and HugoRune mentioned all the points. Strictly speaking you should say what it is doing based on documentation or experience.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger are we 'allowed' to post the CIL?

Comment: @AakashM I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Last I checked, the source code for most of .NET is publicly available, at least up through version 4.0. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Comment: @ChimeraObscura It is available unter the MS-RSL license. *"The Microsoft Reference Source License (MS-RSL) is the most restrictive of the Microsoft source code licenses. The license prohibits all use of source code other than the viewing of the code for reference purposes."* So posting the code on another site is explicitly not allowed. Linking to it would be ok though, but I do not think it is possible to link to individual files.

Comment: @HugoRune - IANAL - Copyright law (at least in the US) allows for "fair use", regardless of what MS license is.  I would think that Royi's use would fall under that umbrella.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to use prime numbers for hash table sizes because it reduces the probability of collisions.

Hash tables typically use the modulo operation to find the bucket where an entry belongs, as you can see in your code:

```
int index = destinationArray[j].hashCode % prime;
```

Suppose your hashCode function results in the following hashCodes among others {x , 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, 6x...}, then all these are going to be clustered in just m number of buckets, where m = table_length/GreatestCommonFactor(table_length, x). (It is trivial to verify/derive this). Now you can do one of the following to avoid clustering:

1. Make sure that you don't generate too many hashCodes that are multiples of another hashCode like in {x, 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, 6x...}.But this may be kind of difficult if your hashTable is supposed to have millions of entries.
2. Or simply make m equal to the table_length by making GreatestCommonFactor(table_length, x) equal to 1, i.e by making table_length coprime with x. And if x can be just about any number then make sure that table_length is a prime number.

(from http://srinvis.blogspot.com/2006/07/hash-table-lengths-and-prime-numbers.html)

```
HashHelpers.GetPrime(this.count * 2)
```

should return a prime number. Look at the definition of HashHelpers.GetPrime().

Comment: It is `GetPrime(2 * this.count)`, not `2 * GetPrime(this.count)`. It looks for the next prime larger than twice the current size therefore increasing the capacity by at least a factor two.

Comment: can you **please** explain/ elaborate the `x , 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, 6x...}, ` thing ? ( with a sample :-) ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary puts all its objects into buckets depending on their GetHashCode value, i.e.
`Bucket[object.GetHashCode() % DictionarySize] = object;`
It uses a prime number for size to avoid the chance of collisions. Presumably a size with many divisors would be bad for poorly designed hash codes.

Answer (score 1):

From a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181531/net-concurrentdictionary-initial-capacity-set-to-arbitrary-prime-number-rather) in SO;

> Dictionary or hash table relies on hashing the key to get a smaller
>   index to look up into corresponding store (array). So choice of hash
>   function is very important. Typical choice is to get hash code of a
>   key (so that we get good random distribution) and then divide the code
>   by a prime number and use reminder to index into fixed number of
>   buckets. This allows to convert arbitrarily large hash codes into a
>   bounded set of small numbers for which we can define an array to look
>   up into. So its important to have array size in prime number and then
>   the best choice for the size become the prime number that is larger
>   than the required capacity. And that's exactly dictionary
>   implementation does.

`List<T>` employs `array`s to store data; and increasing the capacity of an array requires copying the array to a new memory location; which is time consuming. I guess, in order to lower the occurence of copying arrays, list doubles it's capacity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not computer scientist, but ...

Most probabbly its related to a [HashTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)'s [Load factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_factor_%28aeronautics%29) (the last link just a math definition), and for not creating more confusion, for not math auditory, it's important to define that:

```
loadFactor = FreeCells/AllCells
```

this we can write as

```
loadFactor = (AllBuckets - UsedBuckets)/AllBuckets
```

`loadFactor` defines a *probabbilty* of collision in hash map. 
So by using a [Prime Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number),a number that

> ..is a natural number greater than 1 that
>   has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.

we decrease (but do not erase) a risk of collision in our hashmap.

If `loadFactor` tends to `0`, we have more secure hashmap, so we always has to keep it as low as possible. By MS [blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/8a2fb4ad-b3e0-45dd-9c96-7f80409b0ee1), they found out that the value of that `loadFactor` (optimal one) has to be arround `0.72`, so if it becomes bigger, we increase the capacity following nearest prime number.

**EDIT**

To be more clear on this: having *a prime number*, ensures, as mush as it possible, uniform destribution of the hashes in this concrete implementation of the hash we have in .NET dictionary. It's not about efficency of the retrieval of the values, but efficiency of the memory used and collision risk reduction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: -1: This explains (almost) nothing - there is no difference concerning the load factor no matter if the capacity is prime or not.

Comment: @DanielBrückner: AllBuckets == Capacity, using  a prime number *decreases* loadFactor maximum point (0.72 in this case), achievement. Please, provide an explanation on what do you mean *exaclty*.

Comment: 653 items in a table with 907 slots and 720 items in a table with 1000 slots both have a load factor 0.72. How does it matter that the former capacity is prime while the later is not?

Comment: @DanielBrückner: because having a prime number (according to the math definition you can find in link provided) in several implementations of hash (at this point in .NET implementation too) ensures better as possible uniform destribution of the hashes. If you're asking about math proove of this, I repeat, I'm not a CS, but you can find a links to research papers in the wikipedia article linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary` needs some heuristic so that hash code distribution among buckets is more uniform.

.NET's `Dictionary` uses prime number of buckets to do that, and then calculates bucket index like this:

```
int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 2147483647; // make hash code positive
// get the remainder from division - that's our bucket index
int num2 = this.buckets[num % ((int)this.buckets.Length)];
```

When it grows, it doubles the number of buckets and then adds some more to *make the number prime again*.

It's not the only heuristic possible. Java's `HashMap`, for example, takes another approach. The number of buckets there is always a power of 2 and on grow it just *doubles the number of buckets*:

```
resize(2 * table.length);
```

But when calculating bucket index it modifies hash:

```
static int hash(int h) {
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
    return h & (length-1);
}

// from put() method
int hash = hash(key.hashCode()); // get modified hash
int i = indexFor(hash, table.length); // trim the hash to the bucket count
```

`List` on the other hand doesn't need any heuristic, so they didn't bother.

**Addition**: Grow behavior doesn't influence `Add`'s complexity at all. `Dictionary`, `HashMap` and `List` each have amortized `Add` complexity of O(1).

Grow operation takes O(N) but occurs only N-th time, so to cause grow operation we need to call `Add` N times. For N=8 the time it takes to do N `Add`s has the value

> O(1)+O(1)+O(1)+O(1)+O(1)+O(1)+O(1)+O(N) = O(N)+O(N) = O(2N) = O(N)

So, N `Add`s take O(N), then one `Add` takes O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the capacity by a constant factor (instead of for example increasing the capacity by a additive constant) when resizing is required to guarantee some amortized running times. For example adding to or removing from the end of an array based list requires `O(1)` time except when you have to increase or decrease the capacity requiring to copy the list content and therefore requiring `O(n)` time. Changing the capacity by a constant factor guarantees that the amortized runtime is still `O(1)`. The optimal value of the factor depends on the expected usage. Some more information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost).

Choosing the capacity of a hash table to be prime is used to improve the distribution of the items. `bucket[hash % capacity]` will yield a more uniform distribution if `hash` is not uniformly distributed if `capacity` is prime. (I can not give the math behind that but I am looking for a good reference.) The combination of this with the first point is exactly what the implementation does - increasing the capacity by a factor (of at least) 2 and also ensure that the capacity is prime.